# Como fazer paginação de dados com PagedList em Asp.Net MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pagedlist

Tenho uma tabela de usuários com 10.000 cadastros. Quero paginar esses registros usando LIMIT e OFFSET com PagedList mas nao estou conseguindo fazer isso. Atualmente o sistema busca todos os registros para depois paginar e não quero que seja assim, quero paginar de forma real.

Como fazer isso ?

Estou tentando assim.

**Model Search**

```
public class SearchUsuario{

    public IPagedList<ViewUsuario> lista        { get; set; }

    public SearchUsuario(){
        lista = new List<ViewUsuario>().ToPagedList(1, 50);
    }
}
```

**Model View**

```
public class ViewUsuario {

    public String nome { get; set; }
}
```

**Generic DAO**

```
//returns all records 
 public IQueryable<T> GetAll(){
        IQueryable<T> query = context.Set<T>();
        return query;
    }
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult view(int? page){
            int pageNumber = page ?? 1;
            int pageSize = 20;

            SearchUsuario search = new SearchUsuario();
            IQueryable<Usuario> lista = new UsuarioDAO().GetAll().OrderBy(u => u.nome).Skip(pageSize * pageNumber).Take(pageSize); //retorna todos os usuarios
            List<ViewUsuario> listaModel = new List<ViewUsuario>();
            foreach(Usuario u in lista){
                Debug.WriteLine(u.nome);
                ViewUsuario view = new ViewUsuario();
                view.nome = u.nome;
                listaModel.Add(view);
            }
            search.lista = listaModel.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize);
            return View(search);
        }
```

**View HTML**

```
@using PagedList.Mvc
@model SearchUsuario

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "view";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">@Language.Users</div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table id="grid" class="table table-striped table-hover" cellspacing="0">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Nome</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tfoot>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Nome</th>
                            </tr>
                        </tfoot>
                        <tbody>  
                            @foreach (ViewUsuario m in Model.lista){
                                <tr>
                                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(i => m.nome)</td>
                                </tr>
                            }                         
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div><!--/div table-responsive-->
            </div><!--div panel-body -->
            <div class="panel-footer">
                Pagina @Model.lista.PageNumber de @Model.lista.PageCount
                @Html.PagedListPager(Model.lista, page => Url.Action("view", new{
                                                                                page = page                                                                                       
                                                                             }))
            </div><!--/panel-footer-->

        </div><!--/div panel-->
    </div><!--/div col-->
</div><!--/div row-->
```

Comment: Qual é o banco de dados? nessa linha IQueryable<Usuario> lista = new UsuarioDAO().GetAll(); deveria retorna só a quantidade de registro e a quantidade de registros retornados de uma determinada `page`? ou seja, o que tem dentro de `GetAll()`?

Comment: @VirgilioNovic nesta linha `GetAll()` retorna todos os registros. E o banco eh MySQL.

Comment: então o código desse método está errado? tem como colocar na pergunta?

Comment: @VirgilioNovic pronto. Coloquei o `GetAll()` que esta na classe `GenericDAO` e retorna todos os registros

Comment: oh não está dificil de resolver, sem tem como colocar o modelo da classe ViewUsuario?

Comment: @VirgilioNovic postei ai a classe `ViewUsuario` e a alteração que fiz no Controller. No controller paginou, mas na `View HTML` nao mostra que tem outras paginas

Comment: Deu certo a resposta?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se pode fazer assim, já que o método `GetAll()` retorna um `IQueryable<T>` não foi ainda executado pelo banco e pode tranquilamente trabalhar com todas as funcionalidades fora:

```
public ActionResult view(int? page)
{
    int p = page ?? 1;
    int pageSize = 20;

    SearchUsuario search = new SearchUsuario();

    IQueryable<Usuario> lista = new UsuarioDAO()
        .GetAll();      

    search.lista = lista.Select(x => new ViewUsuario 
    {
        nome = x.nome
    })
    .ToPagedList(p, pageSize);

    return View(search);

}
```

dessa forma o dado vai sempre vir paginado e não trará todos os dados da base para depois paginar.

Answer (score 0):

Como eu uso um Model para exibir os dados, eu acabei usando o `StaticPagedList` que faz parte da biblioteca PagedList, e isso resolveu meu problema, além de ter ficado muito performatico.

Fiz assim.

```
public ActionResult view(int? page){            
            int pageNumber = page ?? 1;
            int pageSize = 20;
            int totalRecords = dao.GetAll().Count(); //qtd de registros

            //lista paginando registros
            IEnumerable<ViewUsuario> lista = dao.GetAll()
                                            .OrderBy(u => u.id)
                                            .Skip(pageSize * pageNumber)
                                            .Take(pageSize)
                                            .Select(x => new ViewUsuario{
                                                nome = x.nome,            
                                            });

            //model
            SearchUsuario search = new SearchUsuario();
            search.lista = new StaticPagedList<ViewUsuario>(lista, pageNumber, pageSize, totalRecords);            

            return View(search);
        }
```

Comment: Eu te dei uma solução, você por acaso testou? porque essa que você fez realmente é boa, mas, ao que eu fiz é a mesma coisa que você fez  ...?

Comment: @VirgilioNovic claro que testei, funcionou blzinha, fiz soh uma alteracao no `GetAll()` adicionando um `OrderBy()` que o `Skip()` exige. O problema foi performance, usando sua sugestão levou 45 segundos pra carregar, já usando o StaticPagedList levou 20 segundos, por isso optei por usa-lo, mas o seu funciona blzinha. Vou marcar o seu como certo, obrigado.

Comment: Fernando Paiva, tem algo de errado, porque o meu código é a mesma coisa que o seu, só muda a classe ... não é isso que está dando esse desempenho ruim, talvez seja banco, talvez outros fatores, mas, do código em si não é! posso afirmar porque também uso esse PagedList nos meus projetos e sei com é o seu código interno ... Tem algo de errado no projeto dá uma olhada nisso .... Verifique a parte de indexes do banco, verifique o banco porque até 20 segundos é muita coisa para trazer 20 registros.

Comment: @VirgilioNovic vou fazer isso, vlw pela dica. Me diga uma coisa, vc acha mais performatico usar o PagedList ou o DataTable com Jquery ? qual sua opiniao ?

Comment: O PagedList porque já testei os dois ... mas, cara olha seu banco não pode dar 20 segundos é muito tempo ... !!! blz!

Comment: @VirgilioNovic obrigado